# How to make a navbar stay in one line?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I have a working navbar in the top center of my page. However, when I reduce my resolution, my navbar spreads itself into separate lines. How can I force it to stay in one line?

Here's my css:

```
#navbar {
display:inline-block;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
margin-left:25%;
margin-top:30px;
}

.navbar-li {
display:inline-block;
white-space:nowrap;
background-color:orange;
font-family:Arial;
margin-right:100px;
padding:20px 40px;
}

li {
font-size:20px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="navbar"> 
    <ul>
        <li class="navbar-li">text1</li>
        <li class="navbar-li">text2</li>
        <li class="navbar-li">text3</li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to your navbar

Answer (score 1):

Set `width:` to the amount in pixels that you want your nav bar to always be, do not use a percent. This makes it stay the same size no matter what the screen resolution is.